# Variable size element in embedded function but fixed input and output

Tags: size, simulink, local-variables, pre-allocation

I have a fixed input and output for my simulink embeded function. 
However I would like to compute a variable size element inside the function, (only used for calculation).

Therefore I would prefer not to declare the block as receiving or sending dynamic size signal. (or using coder.varsize)

ex:

```
  K =  find( p_var(:) == 0 );     % p_var is a vector containing some zeros
  p_var(K) = [];                  % p_var is a therefore a varsize vector 
                           % the variability is something I need for reason

  n = length(p_var)               % n is dynamic

  M = ones(10,n)                  % M & L are also dynamic
  L = ones(n,50)

  G = M*L;                        % G is fixed of size [10*50]
```

Here the variable G is always fixed... but I have this type of error :

```
 Dimension 2 is fixed on the left-hand side but varies on the right ([1 x 9] ~= [1 x :?])
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define an upper bound for the size of `p_var`.  This can be done in a couple of ways, such as using `coder.varsize` as shown below.

A couple of other things to note:

1. If `p_var` is an input to your function you cannot change its size,but would need a temporary variable as shown below.
2. You most likely do not want to use `find` as you have done, but should use logical indexing instead.

   `function G = fcn(u)`

   `p_var = u;`

   `coder.varsize('p_var', [10,1]);`

   `p_var(p_var(:) == 0) = []; % p_var is therefore a varsize vector
   the variability is something I need for reason`

   `n = length(p_var);             % n is dynamic`

   `M = ones(10,n);               % M & L are also dynamic`
   `L = ones(n,50);`

   `G = M*L;                        % G is fixed of size [10*50]`

Comment: Thank you ! it works well. 


I think my error using coder.varsize initially was to try to use directly the input of the function and change its size. (which led to the error about variable input/output)


I was a little confused on how to treat memory allocation of varsize element on simulink.